# Mongodb connect failed on MacOS

Tags: mongodb, macos

I download mongodb from https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/community. But when i run `mongo` on terminal, it had errors.

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.2.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2020-03-01T17:35:44.812+0800 E  QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17
@(connect):2:6
2020-03-01T17:35:44.815+0800 F  -        [main] exception: connect failed
2020-03-01T17:35:44.815+0800 E  -        [main] exiting with code 1
```

when I run `mongod` in terminal, there's error below:

```
$ mongod

2020-03-01T17:39:38.409+0800 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2020-03-01T17:39:38.416+0800 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=11072 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=YvandeiMac.local
2020-03-01T17:39:38.416+0800 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.3
2020-03-01T17:39:38.416+0800 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 6874650b362138df74be53d366bbefc321ea32d4
2020-03-01T17:39:38.416+0800 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2020-03-01T17:39:38.416+0800 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2020-03-01T17:39:38.416+0800 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2020-03-01T17:39:38.416+0800 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2020-03-01T17:39:38.416+0800 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2020-03-01T17:39:38.416+0800 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2020-03-01T17:39:38.417+0800 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
2020-03-01T17:39:38.417+0800 I  NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2020-03-01T17:39:38.417+0800 I  -        [initandlisten] Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions.
2020-03-01T17:39:38.417+0800 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2020-03-01T17:39:38.417+0800 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

Comment: IMHO, you might consider using **homebrew** http://brew.sh to download and install packages on macOS.

Comment: The error is included in your `mongod` output: `NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found`. You need to create this directory or specify a `--dbpath` when starting MongoDB. I'd recommend installing via Homebrew as suggested in the [macOS installation guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/#install-mongodb-community-edition), which will set up directories and permissions to manage MongoDB as a service.

Comment: I installed mongodb-community by homebrew and changed the db path. `mongod --dbpath=/Users/user/data/db`. But error still existed. `exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found., terminating`.